# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging Message text and title

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

Using Flutter for the first time and have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging. I can sent a notification from Notification Composer in the Firebase Console. I can see in the debug-console on Android whilst the app is in foreground that it receives the data I have set in Custom Data.

```
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('on message $message');
  },
```

However I am wondering how to get not only the Custom Data but also the Message Text and Message Title.

Comment: I think this is not possible. The text and title is used only if the app is in background. I'm not very sure about that, but that's my understanding. You can send text and title also in data to receive it in the app as well.

Comment: I think I will try this approach to sent this in data as well. Shouldn't be an issue!

Comment: The message payloads are handled differently for Android and iOS. Since you're using Flutter I'm not sure what to suggest. Are you testing with both types of devices?

Comment: I used Xcode with Swift natively before and was able to get the payload. Now I am trying to use Flutter and being new to Android it seems push notifications work a bit differently. I mean when the app is not active in the background and you receive a push the notification shows the message payload. So for sure it is delivered to the device, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to get the string for title and body that comes in the message object, you can do something like this:

```
final title = message['notification']['title'] ?? '';
final body = message['notification']['body'] ?? '';
```